# Highly efficient multi-dimensional filtering in Excel with millions of data points

Tags: microsoft-excel

**Situation:**

Let's assume I have some millions of data points with different information (i.e., country, product, etc.) over time that I want to filter based on some user input. The exemplary data is stored in the range `A1:I21`, and the user input is collected in the range `L1:M5`, with country in `L1`, product in `L2`, unit in `L3`, market in `L4`, and time range in `L5` (start) and `M5` (end), based on e.g., data validation lists.

**Aim:**

The end result should be an array that captures the values for all products over time. It is important that it also captures the products that do not exist in a particular country. Given the large number of data points, it should be a method (ideally non-VBA) that is very efficient, assuming frequent changes in user input. The approaches described below work, but Excel becomes very slow and calculations take quite a long time. Are there any suggestions on a more optimized approach?

**Possible Approaches:**

One tempting approach would be to use the `FILTER` function, but that doesn't work because the output for country B, product 3 will not be captured with #N/A.

For the following two approaches (i.e., `XLOOKUP` and `INDEX`), I use the following formula in cell `O2` to capture the required date range, and put the unique products (1, 2, 3) in range `P1:R1`, respectively.

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER($E$1:$I$1,($E$1:$I$1>=$L$5)*($E$1:$I$1<=$M$5)))
```

*XLOOKUP approach:*

One possible approach would be to use a nested `XLOOKUP` (formula below in the range `P2:R2`, since the formula spills). First I look for the correct time period and then I filter for the other user inputs.

```
=XLOOKUP($O$2#,$A$1:$I$1,
XLOOKUP(1,($B$1:$B$21=P$1)*($A$1:$A$21=$L$1)*($C$1:$C$21=$L$3)*($D$1:$D$21=$L$4),$A$1:$I$21,
NA(),0,1))
```

*INDEX/MATCH approach:*

Another possible approach is to use `INDEX/MATCH` (formula below in range `P2:R4`, since the formula doesn't spill). The procedure is very similar to the XLOOKUP approach.

```
=INDEX(INDEX($A$1:$I$21,,MATCH($O2,$A$1:$I$1,0)),
MATCH(1, ($B$1:$B$21=P$1)*($A$1:$A$21=$L$1)*($C$1:$C$21=$L$3)*($D$1:$D$21=$L$4), 0))
```

**Data:**

```
country product unit market  2000  2005  2010  2015  2020
A          1    EUR  local   137   982   557   574   423
A          1    EUR  global  866   133   179   139   939
A          1    %    local   0.5   0.14  0.36  0.41  0.5
A          1    %    global  0.9   0.91  0.6   0.98  0.03
A          2    EUR  local   722   797   115   599   658
A          2    EUR  global  869   620   165   724   171
A          2    %    local   0.68  0.2   0.09  0.07  0.78
A          2    %    global  0.08  0.83  0.39  0.05  0.55
A          3    EUR  local   235   979   593   273   510
A          3    EUR  global  302   244   741   850   569
A          3    %    local   0.03  0.31  0.44  0.54  0.57
A          3    %    global  0.97  0.17  0.04  0.2   0.62
B          1    EUR  local   526   864   822   330   668
B          1    EUR  global  846   791   214   583   780
B          1    %    local   0.56  0.86  0.32  0.78  0.18
B          1    %    global  0.54  0.21  0.18  0.42  0.16
B          2    EUR  local   222   353   831   595   161
B          2    EUR  global  289   431   192   392   571
B          2    %    local   0.14  0.77  0.1   0     0.44
B          2    %    global  0.65  0.36  0.81  0.37  0.89
```

**User Input:**

```
Country  B  
product  1  
unit     EUR    
market   global 
time     2005 2015
```

**Desired Output:**

```
       1    2    3
2005  791  431  #N/A
2010  214  192  #N/A
2015  583  392  #N/A
```

**Excel-Sheet:**

[image: Excel]

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @ScottCraner Office/Excel 365

Comment: Excel is not really the right software for such huge datasets, it will always be inherently rather slow. You should better use a database management system, such as one of these: https://clickup.com/blog/free-database-software/

Comment: @1NN I totally agree with you that Excel is not the ideal software for this, but in this particular use case Excel is the only option. Thus, I want to optimize the procedure to the extent possible.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9143281/1189711

Comment: Power Query. This is what it was built for. Spreadsheet formulas are not the answer here if the data is as large as you say.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar to you, tough with way less data. I had to let clients select some filter criteria in a user-friendly way, and then 3 different sheets would be filtered for them (we assume clients do not know how to filter using autofilter themselves).

The solution I have reached rigth now includes several lists created using data validation, a hidden sheet used for calculations and other stuff, and VBA that includes a intersect method (that works if you select "Change" event in the Sheet). Inside VBA:

```vb
    'Event code, Target variable contains the cell or range that has been changed
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 
 Dim xWs As Worksheet
 On Error Resume Next
 
'Interesect method returns a range object of a rectangular intersection of two or more cell ranges
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
 
    'Select Case statment performs one out of several groups of statements based on a condition
    Select Case Range("B2")
    
            'Different texts in the cell ("Cases" apply different filters through macros
        Case "-":
        Set xWs = Worksheets("Sheet2")
        xWs.Range("H1").AutoFilter Field:=8
        
          Set xWs = Worksheets("Sheet3")
        xWs.Range("H1").AutoFilter Field:=8
        
          Set xWs = Worksheets("Sheet4")
        xWs.Range("H1").AutoFilter Field:=8
        
        Set xWa = Worksheets("Sheet5")
        xWa.Range("H1").AutoFilter Field:=8
 
        'If text in cell H1 is equal to "Yes" a macro is run
        Case "1 circuito": macroname

    'Stops Select Case statement
    End Select
End If
```

And a macro example that filters (located in modules folder in VBA):

```vb
    Sub Filter_Example()
    'Filters Sheet1 by X
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Application.Volatile
    On Error Resume Next

    Set xWs = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    xWs.Range("H1").AutoFilter 8, "=1", Operator:=xlOr, 
    Criteria1:="=1"

    End Sub
```

There is more code that displays which filter is active at a given moment, and a force.calc solution that solves problems with user-defined functions (even if we declare them volatile). The force_recalc solution I have may not be a good solution for your huge dataset, but thats not for me to decide. Anyway,if you need those snippets, ask for them and I will provide. I hope this helps, or if another person suggests a better solution, I would be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to reread this ask, and IF Country/Product/Unit/Market are all unique (can be used as a composite index) then you could just use a pivot table.

[image]

You could add slicers or add a unique index to use as an additional row parameter if country/product/unit/market are not unique

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formula you can use:

`=LET(ftr,FILTER(A:I,(A:A=L1)*(C:C=L3)*(D:D=L4)),vert,VSTACK(A1:I1,ftr),HSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(vert,2),FILTER(vert,(A1:I1>=L5)*(A1:I1<=M5))))`

[image: filter]

You can also include TRANSPOSE to change the orientation of the result.